# Question regarding Qur'an 5:51

Tags: quran, hadith, fiqh, practical-islam, sunnah

I am confused regarding this verse. I have many friends who are non-muslim, but have helped me in many things, and I have helped them too. Should I break my ties of friendship with them??
In the context of this verse, does "Auliya" mean friend in general or does it mean guardian/protector???

Comment: I think the site has many answers explaining and addressing the verse 5:51, have you done some prior search on the site? What are you missing regarding the given answers and posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced verse is talking about the context of warfare (hostile Jewish/Christian militants), as in: do not take the Jews nor Christians as allies (in battles), forming coalitions against the believers (Muslims). So if your friends are righteous, virtuous people who don't pose a negative influence upon you, and don't lead you astray from the righteous path (your religion), then you don't have to break ties with them. Otherwise, find friends who aid you in doing the best of (ethical) deeds that please Allah Subhanu Wa Ta'la, because at the end, this is our ultimate goal in life.

Also, read the following verses: 60:8 and 16:125.

Comment: The context is regarding not befriending those Jews and Christians who went against their own scriptures, fabricate laws, doctrines and dogmas and make a mockery of the beliefs of Muslims. It's not restricted to warfare.

Comment: @Afiq And which scholar said that? I didn't bring anything from my own, that's what the big scholar Al-Tabari said, and Al-Baghawi. Go read their Tafseers...

Comment: I considered the context more.

Comment: Read from verse 30

Comment: @Afiq So I take your interpretation over Imam Al-Tabari, Al-Baghawi, and Al-Qurtubi? They very much considered context, Hadiths, and historical evidences so...

Comment: The reputed scholars and Imams, no matter how loved and honored, are not necessarily the measuring rod. The Noble Kalam of Allah SWT and the Prophetic Sunnah offer the final word on everything, at least on those they are not silent upon. Btw it's not my interpretation, these are ahkam verses.