# Is it haram to befriend a non muslim?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, non-muslim, kufr, friendship

I actually am a student who study in school, most of the students in that school are non muslim, I have a friend there who always helps me with my work and gives me his notes whenever I need it and he is always kind to me, he has been my friend for 8 years, he never said anything to me about my religion or anything and infact he doesn't allow other bully students to tell me anything about my religion, we don't hangout after school but we just sometimes chat about notes and sometimes some other important stuff. I don't do haram things like wishing him on his religious festival or something like that. But I heard that it is haram to befriend a non muslim, so am I committing sin for this?

Comment: I guess this question or alike has been addressed around ten times on the site have you checked those before asking?

Comment: in brief, you can have non-muslim friends as long as they do not hinder you from belief, see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/225/is-it-haraam-to-have-non-muslim-friends/228#228 https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69184/question-regarding-quran-551 https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29794/is-it-acceptable-to-make-friends-with-a-christian-at-school/30291#30291

Comment: Sorry for not searching before asking the question, I actually saw one question like this and it didn't exactly highlited my type of problem but an another question, sorry for not searching